# 7-zip error:Extracting META-INF/AIR/hash-Unsupported Method

Tags: zip, adobe-air, extract

i get this error when extracting an .air file of botanicula:

this is the only error when extracting with 7-Zip on Xubuntu 11.04

```
7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=de_DE.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: /media/H2SD/Botanicula.air

Extracting  mimetype
Extracting  META-INF/AIR/application.xml
Extracting  META-INF/AIR/hash     Unsupported Method
Extracting  BotaniculaLinux.swf
Extracting  data/01/1_01.swf
Extracting  data/01/1_02.swf
Extracting  data/01/1_03.swf
...
```

is this important?

does it mean, that the hash is not correct?
if so, how can i stop the 7-zip gui from deleting all it has already extracted due to this unimportant error?

Comment: `Copyright (c) 1999-2009` seems a bit old. Did you install updates on your system?

Comment: There are other ZIP tools available, too. Try `unzip` on the console. GUI tools available are XArchiver and file-roller.

Comment: BTW: to **use** the air file, it [seems you don't need to extract it](http://askubuntu.com/q/123729/20661).

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this whole issue is not important. I don't know a real reason, why I have to extract the Air file