# How can I install Botanicula?

Tags: installation, games

I just got Botanicula. When I unzip it, there is just a `.air` file. What do I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [install the Adobe AIR Runtime](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air) before you can install the game.

The latest version for Linux is 2.6. Note that additional steps are required if you are running a 64-bit system, Ubuntu 12.04, or both. Instructions are included in the link above.

Once Adobe AIR is installed, double-click the `Botanicula.air` file to install the game. Select the default options. (The install can take a while.)

The application `BotaAIRlinux` will now appear as an application in your dash. Click on it to run.

(For detailed discussion of this procedure see http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php/topic,3729.0.html - includes additional links, and instructions for other Linuxes.)